# flexbox how to achieve this specific layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

Like in the image - http://i65.tinypic.com/aa7ndw.png Examples and live flex configurators are explain only simple examples, or I just don't get it.

Will I be able to use media queries to for example not display a4 when < 800px?

I have always used float and flex is somehow 'different' anyway I would like to know it better, so any help is appreciated.

[flex specific example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BgUh.png)

Comment: Please add codes that you have tried using flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `display: flex` to a container and its child elements will be displayed in flex. For this layout, you will want to wrap the elements when width is already filled for the current row.

The header and footer will be `width: 100%`, taking a full row. #a3 and #a4 will have `flex: 1` to distribute the width of their row, taking each one 50% of the width.

```css
div.flex-container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#a1, #a2{
  width: 100%;
}

#a3, #a4{
  flex: 1;
}

#a5, #a6, #a7{
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* Example styles */
div{
  text-align: center;
}
#a1{
  background-color: red;
}
#a2{
  background-color: limegreen;
}
#a3{
  background-color: royalblue;
}
#a4{
  background-color: cyan;
}
#a5, #a6, #a7{
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="a1">a1</div>
  <div id="a3">a3</div>
  <div id="a4">a4
    <div id="a5">a5</div>
    <div id="a6">a6</div>
    <div id="a7">a7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="a2">a2</div>
</div>
```

And yeah, you can use media queries as normal

```css
div.flex-container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#a1, #a2{
  width: 100%;
}

#a3, #a4{
  flex: 1;
}

#a5, #a6, #a7{
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
  #a4{
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Example styles */
div{
  text-align: center;
}
#a1{
  background-color: red;
}
#a2{
  background-color: limegreen;
}
#a3{
  background-color: royalblue;
}
#a4{
  background-color: cyan;
}
#a5, #a6, #a7{
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="a1">a1</div>
  <div id="a3">a3</div>
  <div id="a4">a4
    <div id="a5">a5</div>
    <div id="a6">a6</div>
    <div id="a7">a7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="a2">a2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gerard thank you for your answer. I have one more question - in answer.